# How to take the beginning and end parts of a list with simpler syntax?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

**So** basically you have a table of some values, let's call it `a`:

```
a=Table[n,{n,10}];
(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}*)
```

And you want to take the beginning and end parts of the table, within the same line, and do *something* with them. It is my intention to change them all to 0, but really you could change them to some other variable, say `b`. We want the parts of the list that do not include some inner values, we'll do `{4,5,6}` which happen to correspond to the indexes 4 through 6, convenient, no?

```
a[[Cases[a, (Except[Alternatives @@ Range[4, 6]])]]] = b; a
(*{b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}*)
```

### **What's a simpler syntax for this? How can we call the end and beginning values of a list in a simpler manner?**

```
a[[Cases[a, (Except[Alternatives @@ Range[4, 6]])]]]
(*{1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}*)
```

The ideal input would be, to me, something like

```
a[[1;;3;7;;10]]
(*{1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}*)
```

But this gives

```
(*{7, 8, 9, 10}*)
```

As expected.

## **How can we simplify the syntax to call the beginning and end parts of a list, leaving out some chosen middle portion?**

Comment: `Select[ a, !  MemberQ[ {4, 5, 6}, #] & ]`

Comment: @LouisB that's a decently creative approach! +1 Put this as an answer so it is easier for others to find in the future? Also, if you put in `Range[4,6]` that might be a better way to make it more general! As opposed to, say, if you had a list of 100 elements, or 1000, or 10000, it might get a bit type-y to input `{40, 41, 42, 43, . . , 59, 60}`.

Comment: `Complement[ a,  {4, 5, 6} ]`

Comment: Cheating a little, we could write `(a[[#]] = b) & /@ {1 ;; 3, 7 ;; 10}`.

Comment: @WReach Dude! What! How did I miss that one?! I _*LOVE*_ pure functions. WOW. Hah, +1 well deserved. Y'all should put these as answers! ;D Wow that's even a new way to do pure functions I hadn't considered prior, I was gonna ask what was up with the use of parenthesis, but I quickly saw why....very _very_ nice, WReach.

Comment: What's supposed to happen if your table of values is `Table[n^2,{n,10}]` or if values are not monotonic? It seems the value and the position of the value are conflated in the Q and the A's.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I’m not sure what you mean, or what the problem would be, you’d still take the initial through the final index values? There should still be a 4th, 5th, and 6th index to be kept, yeah? Do you reference my comment about “convenient, no?” In the question? I had written that before I used `Range[4,6]` to replace `a[[4;;6]]`

Comment: If it's the values, then in `Table[n^2,{n,10}]` the initial segment would be the span `1 ;; 1` and the final segment would be `3 ;; 10` and the excluded segment (the positions not to be changed) would be `2 ;; 2`, if the excluded values were 4, 5, 6 -- no?

Comment: If the text of the question and desired outcome is unchanged if `Table[n^2,{n,10}]` is substituted for `Table[n,{n,10}]`, then it, or better yet, `Table[10+n,{n,10}]`, would be a clearer answer. But it seems to me that your `Cases` and your `Span` examples would not agree if I changed `a` but didn't change the `4` to `6`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I understand what you’re asking now. This is just a SWE. It’s indexed values that we’re after, because of the problems you mention. You have some number of values in your set, in this case 10, whether it is of `n` or `n^2`, and you only want to preserve some middle content, or alter the surrounding contents. It’s always indexed values you should be inputting imo, as I don’t think you can have a table or set with missing indexes? And if so, it is well outside the scope of this question or what I’m after. You’d always be preserving some inner set of indexes, 4, 5, & 6, in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I posted an answer.  See if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** You can also try [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
a = Range[10];
a = MapAt[b &, a, {{;; 3}, {7 ;;}}]
```

> {b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}

Or `ReplaceAll`

```
a = Range[10];
a /. Alternatives @@ Drop[a, 4;;6] -> b
```

> {b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}

**Original answer:** Try [`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html):

```
Drop[Range @ 10, {4, 6}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}

```
Drop[Range @ 10, 4 ;; 6]
```

> > {1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}

```
Drop[CharacterRange["a", "j"], {4, 6}]
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "i", "j"}

Comment: Hah, shot myself in the foot with my end question...That works to get the values, but I'm unsure of the readability when we do `a[[Drop[Range@10, {4, 6}]]] = b; a`. Though, it is a nice implementation and one I had not considered. I'm hoping to find something that is not too over-encumbered, in order to sit in a publication. This is much nicer than the original try of mine, and it only uses the definition of the neglected characters. Quite nice, actually, the more I debate it! Much more general of an approach. +1

Comment: I've accepted your answer based on these parameters: generality of implementation, multiple versions, & the number of votes. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If it is okay to perform two assignments instead of one, then we can write:

```
(a[[#]] = b) & /@ {1 ;; 3, 7 ;; 10}
```

`Scan` is probably better since it does not bother constructing the result list that we are just going to discard anyway:

```
Scan[(a[[#]] = b) &, {1 ;; 3, 7 ;; 10}]
```

Comment: Well aaactually--that was the original reason for this question, and I probably could have written that....but I can't remember what cup of coffee I was on at that point! Regardless, this is a great implementation of a pure function applied to an index being used in a functional reassignment. This is technically in one line too, which satisfied my original criteria! Very cool. I wonder if this can be shorted at all for some sort-of code-golf-like...thing...answer? (Hint-hint, but it'd require some user thought) Oooooh scan, yessiree this is a great one, `Scan` needs more use these days, imo.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this?:

```
ReplacePart[Range@10, i_ /; Not[4 <= i <= 6] :> b]
(*  {b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}  *)
```

Comment: Wow nice!! I like the use of `RuleDelayed`, am I correct in understanding that you could use either `Table[n,{n,10}]` or `Table[n^2,{n,10}]` and we should see the 4th-6th indexed values preserved, as `ReplacePart` replaces the ith index? The use of `Not` provides a good deal of readability as well.

Comment: @CATrevillian Yes, it depends only on the index (part/position), not the value.

Answer (score 5):

By far the simplest way is to do it in two lines:

```
a = Table[RandomReal[], {n, 10}];
a[[1 ;; 3]] = b;
a[[7 ;; 10]] = b;
a
```

This gives the output:

> {b, b, b, 0.378846, 0.475894, 0.533768, b, b, b, b}

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Union[]` to perform this operation in a simpler manner:

```
a[[Range[1, 3] \[Union] Range[7, 10]]]
(*{1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}*)
```

But this is still decently messy, and the readability is not too high. Perhaps someone else has a better method?

```
a[[Range[1, 3] \[Union] Range[7, 10]]] = b; a
(*{b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using `TakeList`:** (introduced 14 Sep 2017)

```
alist = Range[10];
```

*Examples*

```
Flatten@TakeList[alist, {4 ;; 6}]
```

> {4, 5, 6}

```
TakeList[alist, {3, -4}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}

---

```
idx = Flatten@TakeList[alist, {3, -4}]
SubsetMap[Map[b &], alist, idx]
```

or

```
MapAt[b &, alist, List /@ idx]
```

> {b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}

Answer (score 3):

For me, the least fussy approach involves using `ArrayPad[]` twice:

```
ArrayPad[ArrayPad[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {-3, -4}], {3, 4}, b]
   {b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}
```

Comment: Can this be used to rip out the middle portion and present just the edge parts? I suspect so, but I don’t understand this well enough on the surface. Thanks in advance! Very nice usage :)

Comment: "rip out the middle portion and present just the edge parts" - for that case, I would be using `Take[]`/`Part[]` instead. `ArrayPad[]` is designed to act on both ends of a list, either by adding or removing elements (depending on the signs of the integers used in the second argument).

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
Range[10] // #[[;; 3]]~Join~#[[7 ;;]] &
```

Answer (score 3):

With `ReplaceAt` (since 13.1):

```
ReplaceAt[Range[10], _ -> b, {{;; 3}, {7 ;;}}]
```

{b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Cases`:

```
lst = Range[10];

Cases[lst, x_ :> If[And @@ Thread[x != Range[4, 6]], b, x]]

(*{b, b, b, 4, 5, 6, b, b, b, b}*)
```